# second number is being ignored in calc()

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I have a web page with a header, menu, wrapper and footer. I'm trying to make the footer sticky by setting the height of all the components apart from the wrapper and then using calc to determine the min-height of said wrapper.
The browser picks up the calc function in inspect element but when I check the height of the wrapper it is always 100% and not 100% - 545px and I don't know why. I've tested it in firefox and chrome and on different size monitors but no joy. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
#wrapper-fullwidth{
/* Firefox */
min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 545px);
/* WebKit */
min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 545px);
/* Opera */
min-height: -o-calc(100% - 545px);
/* Standard */
min-height: calc(100% - 545px);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CLJX/)

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: JSFiddle please but my guess is that px equivalent to 100% is a variable number so the base 'number' does not exist.

Comment: Opera (Presto) doesn't support `calc()` (and neither do most mobile browsers), so there's no reason to provide prefixes for it.

Comment: @cimmanon as support goes it's covered by almost all modern browsers: [link](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: In your fiddle, you need to set the number of pixels to the correct value (60 not 545), also apply `overflow: auto` to the main wrapper to prevent collapsing margin effects.

Comment: @MarcAudet I tried to implement your answer into my layout and i'm getting random whitespace [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CLJX/3/)

Comment: You have the collapsing white space effect, see fix at: http://jsfiddle.net/4CLJX/4/ you need to add `overflow: auto` to the wrapper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try something like this.

If this is your HTML (or similar):

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main">Main</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

the CSS needs to look like:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.main {
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    min-height: -o-calc(100% - 90px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 90px);
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.header, .footer {
    height: 45px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

You need to set a height to `html` and `body` or else the percentage height in `.main` is not defined.

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2e3dK/

Comment: I have set the html and body. I also can't use position: fixed for the footer div either. I added a jsfiddle to the question.

Comment: I misread your original question and modified my solution.  It works regardless of how you position the footer.  See updated fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the px on the end makes them strings and not ints.

Try this:

```
min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 545);
```

Update:
since that most likely wont work, try using height and not min-height

```
height: -moz-calc(100% - 545px);
```

Comment: Doubtful...other wise it could be 545px, 545em, 545cm! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Could it then be because of the min-height, since it then can be larger, so it's necessary to use height instead?